# The component does not work asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that makes a request and displays a list of jobs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Jobs } from '../components/Jobs.component';

export const Fixed = () => {
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems();
    }, []);

    async function getItems() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8081/api/fixed/list';
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        setJobs(data.jobsList);
        console.log(jobs);
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {jobs.map(job => (
                <div>
                    <Jobs job={job} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

My problem is that the first console outputs an array of jobs, but the second console displays an empty array. And an empty value is passed to the job component, which causes an error.

He does not have time to write the work in a state? Where am I wrong?

Comment: The value isn't updated until you call useState again, the next time the whole function gets called (i.e. when the component is re-rendered).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then why does the map start working and pass an undefined value to the component?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to tell you that. Move the log *outside* the async function, so you actually see what it's trying to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## State updates are run asynchroniously

The reason your `console.log` shows an empty array is because `setJobs` runs asynchroniously and will update jobs value on next render. Looking at [react setState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) *(same as useState react hooks)* :

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state.

And so

> **setState() does not always immediately update the component.** It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Comment: nothing to do with batching - it works the same with single state. and it would work the same even if it wasn't asynchronous, but that's a good metaphor I guess

Answer (score 2):

Method `setJobs` needs some time to change state so `console.log` runs faster than value changes.

You should render list if the array length is bigger than 0.

```
{jobs.length && jobs.map(job => <Jobs job={job} />)}
```

Comment: it would work the same if you would wrap it into `setTimeout(() => console.log(jobs), 1000)`, the value of `jobs` inside the closure will never change. but the advice with render is good.

Answer (score 0):

`const ... jobs ...` is a constant - it will be a different constant in 2 different renders, but it will not change value during a single render

The `jobs` inside `getItems` is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and will reference to the value from the first render, while `setJobs` will only change the value in second render.

It's similar to the following:

```js
const rememberJobs = (jobs) => () => console.log(jobs)
const first = rememberJobs([])
const second = rememberJobs([1, 2, 3])
first()
second()
```